# How to check cron modified time?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

How to find `cron` job modified time in Ubuntu, For Example: when the `cron` job has been modified or changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check cron logs. Or you can use command

```
stat /var/spool/cron/www-data
```

This will give you modification file of the file where are stored your cron jobs

For Ubuntu 14.04 seems command needs to be

```
stat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
```

Comment: Romeo,
above command not working and i am running a cron in www-data user

Comment: yes that is what i tried, but its not working.

command: stat /var/spool/cron/www-data

Comment: Error: stat: cannot stat ‘/var/spool/cron/www-data’: No such file or directory

Comment: In such case this user do not have cron record